# Matlab/Simulink Casting mxarray to double

Tags: matlab, csv, parsing, simulink

Errors:

-"Function output 'y' cannot be an mxArray in this context. Consider
preinitializing the output variable with a known type."

-"Brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type."

I need to make a simulation for streets and crossings.
I do the pathfinding of cars outside of matlab, and have the routes in a csv file.
Now I need to set the next knot the car has to go to depending on its destination.
I have the destination_ID and need to read the next_knot_ID from the table.

To read out the table I have tried different things the most promising so far using readtable and readcell:

```
function y = fcn()
coder.extrinsic('readtable'); //makes matlab function work in simulink
temp=readtable("test.xlsx");  //should read the table 
temp2=temp(1:1,1:1);
y = temp2;
```

The data in temp now has the type mxArray. I tried a lot of different things to get outputs but usually the main error is something along the line of:

"Function output 'y' cannot be an mxArray in this context. Consider preinitializing the output variable with a known type."

or any flavour of "You cant parse like that(here)" imaginable.
For context the output of the function is currently simply connected to a display in Simulink, since I  only need the numeric value of the next_knot_ID to guide the car.

**!!!!I've found a solution!!!!**

For each of the 2 main errors:

-"Function output 'y' cannot be an mxArray in this context. Consider
preinitializing the output variable with a known type." - y needs to
be initialized somehow to give an output. The only way I found that
works is setting `y = 0.0`.

-"Brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type." - turns
out tables and cells dont like being read. I found a solution by
casting the tables into arrays with `table2array` and then reading
the
value out of the array.

A variant using `readtable()` :

```
function y = fcn()
    %make matlab function usable in simulink
    coder.extrinsic('readtable'); 
    %can also be written directly into the readtable/xlsxread/readcell
    filepath = 'test.xlsx'; %works with .csv as well
    range = 'B2:C3';
    %my feelings tell me this should neither be necessary nor possible
    y = 0.0; % Initialize as a double scalar
    %reading the file
    temp = readtable(filepath,Range=range);
    %cast to array
    temp2 = table2array(temp);
    %use or output the data (double)
    index = 1; %the index in the array where the desired data lies
    temp3 = temp2(index);
y = temp3;
```

A variant using `readcell()`:

```
function y = fcn()
    %make matlab function usable in simulink
    coder.extrinsic('readcell');
    %can also be written directly into the readtable/xlsxread/readcell
    filepath = 'test.xlsx'; %works with .csv as well
    range ='B2:C3';
    %my feelings tell me this should neither be necessary nor possible
    y = 0.0; % Initialize as a double scalar
    %reading the file
    temp = readcell(filepath,Range=range);
    %cast to array
    temp2 = cell2mat(temp);
    %use or output the data (double)
    index = 1; %the index in the array where the desired data lies
    temp3 = temp2(index);
y = temp3;
```

Don't use `xlsread()`:

```
function y = fcn(c)
    coder.extrinsic('xlsread');
    filepath='test.xlsx';
    range='B2:B2';
    y = 0.0; % Initialize as a double scalar

    %my understanding of this is lackluster, but it works 
    [temp, ~ , ~] = xlsread('test.xlsx', range);

y = temp;
```

Comment: `temp` is a table, when using parenthesis indexing, you get another table. Use curly braces instead: `temp2=temp{1,1}`.

Comment: By the way, that error message is terrible and stupid. Every value in MATLAB is an `mxArray` internally. But you only know this if you write MEX-files, the regular user is not confronted with that name ever.